# Not being able to run bash script on windows

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying hard to run a bash script on windows but the message I am getting is "Sorry, only Linux and MacOS are supported."

I have installed Cygwin and Clink in order to be able to run sh scripts on windows platform but still it is of no avail.

Here is my bash script,

```
#!/bin/bash  
for ((j=0;j<10;j++)); do   
  rtg map -i sample_NA19240/SRR003988 -t hg19 -o map_sample_NA19240/SRR003988-  $j --start-read=$[j*1000000] --end-read=$[(j+1)*1000000]   
done
```

Answer (score 1):

It's in the program you are using, "rtg" :

```
# Pre-flight safety-belts
if [ "$(uname -s)" != "Linux" ] && [ "$(uname -s)" != "Darwin" ]; then
    # If you comment this check out you are on your own :-)
    echo "Sorry, only Linux and MacOS are supported."
    exit 1
```

You can try the "suggestion", that is, remove the check in the file installer/rtg. If it works, you are lucky. Else use a vm or ask the rtg author.

Comment: +1 for diagnosing the problem; there is another alternative, however: the utility comes in a (64-bit-only) Windows version too - download it from [here](https://github.com/RealTimeGenomics/rtg-tools/releases). Cygwin is capable of calling Windows CLIs from Bash scripts.

Comment: Thanks smarquis and mklement! Actually i am using Windows version of RTG but still it is giving me the same message. Maybe the program is not configured to be run on windows using that bash script.

Comment: Exactly, on windows you need to call the provided rtg.bat, not the rtg bash script.